# Android - how to change the way proguard rename variables

Tags: android, proguard, obfuscation

Is it possible to change the way proguard rename variables. For example I have a class with variables:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int variable1 = 1;
    private int variable2 = 2;
    private int variable3 = 3;
    private int variable4 = 4;
}
```

After obfuscation, variables renamed to: a,b,c,d accordingly. Is there some settings to rename variables another way, I mean not like in alphabetical order but like random or even in tandem with digits ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `-obfuscationdictionary <file>` to your ProGuard configuration to specify a file containing a list of words to use for generating obfuscated names. Variables will be renamed in the order specified on that file, so they will no longer be sequential letters like 'a,b,c,...'.

From their [docs](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html):

> **-obfuscationdictionary filename**
>   Specifies a text file from which all valid words are used as obfuscated field and method names. By default, short names like 'a', 'b', etc. are used as obfuscated names. With an obfuscation dictionary, you can specify a list of reserved key words, or identifiers with foreign characters, for instance. [...]

Comment: thank you for answer, but could you clarify where exactly should I add this file (in the assets folder or other) and how it should looks ?

Comment: The path is relative to the project's root and I believe it should have a list of letters/words, one per line.